# SVG Filter performance issues

Tags: javascript, html, svg, alphablending, svg-filters

Using a blend mode & filter is causing strange performance issues as the filters stray further from the 0x0 point.

```
<filter id="flashlight-filter-0" x="0" y="-10%" width="4" height="3">
    <feOffset result="light0" in="SourceGraphic" dx="-105" dy="-100"></feOffset>
    <feOffset result="light1" in="SourceGraphic" dx="95" dy="100"></feOffset>
    <feBlend result="blend1" in="light0" in2="light1" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
</filter>
```

A minimal example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/vxg3Lmxz/ - Watch as you move the mouse towards the lower right end of the image, there is an almighty drop in fps, it seems to be the same across all browsers.

Does anyone have tips on improving performance? Alternatively, does anyone know of a different method to achieve this effect?

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chromium 32 and Opera 12.16 with no noticable drops (reasonable spec pc)

Comment: doesn't run for me at all in FF/windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not working in FF because you are using `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` in your mousemove event.  It would be better to use jQuery's `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`, which hides the differences between browser event objects;

```
$('#flashlight-svg-0').mousemove(function(e) {
    var x, y;
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    $('[result="light1"]').attr('dx', x);
    $('[result="light1"]').attr('dy', y);
});
```

Once that is fixed, it works fine on all browsers.  I am not seeing any noticeable drop off in speed as you are reporting.

Your method of doing the flashlight is quite complicated.  But I am guessing you are doing it that way for consistency across browsers?

You can achieve the same flashlight effect a lot more simply using a filter with `feDiffuseLighting`.  However the browser implementations of lighting filters are a bit buggy/inconsistent.

```
    <filter id="flashlight-filter-0">
        <feDiffuseLighting surfaceScale="1" diffuseConstant="20"
                           lighting-color = "#ddd" result="diffOut">
            <feSpotLight id="spot"
                         x="400" y="400" z="1000"
                         pointsAtX="-400" pointsAtY="-400"
                         specularConstant="1"
                         limitingConeAngle="6"/>
        </feDiffuseLighting>
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="diffOut" operator="arithmetic"
                      k1="1" k2="0" k3="0" k4="0"/>
    </filter>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vxg3Lmxz/3/).  This works well on Chrome, but looks different in FF and would need some tweaking to make it match Chrome.

Comment: How could I create multiple spotlights with your model?

Comment: Create two spotlight filters and merge them.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vxg3Lmxz/4/  It's not exactly fast though.

Answer (score 1):

A less elegant but more cross-browser way to do this is to use a variable opacity overlay div and use javascript to change its position. Just using CSS.

```
<img id="target" src="http://www.hexapolis.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Stonehenge_curious_aspects_1.jpg"></img>
<div id="overflow-container">

   <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
#target{
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#overflow-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: -600px;
  left: -300px;
  height:1600px;
  width:1600px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);

background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 5%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

Use JavaScript to change the top/left of the overlay div. If you want multiple spotlights though, you'll have to use masks or write a filter with multiple spotlight definitions.